# if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint and $U_a \subset A$ and $U_b \subset B$, then $U_a \times B \cap A \times U_b = U_a \times U_b$?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

> Let $A = \{a,b\}, B = \{c,d\}$ and $U_a=\{a\}, U_b = \{d\}$, then $U_a \times B \cap A \times U_b = U_a \times U_b$

I'm reading about product topology and my set theory is a bit rusty. There was a problem that had this kind of setup and I couldn't find a way to prove it.

It seems that the general version of this would be that if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint and $U_a \subset A$ and $U_b \subset B$, then $U_a \times B \cap A \times U_b = U_a \times U_b$?

I tried to approach this by inclusion exclusion, but don't now how to work with the cartesian products. If I pick $x \in U_a \times B$, then $x$ is of the form say $x=(x_{U_a}, x_B)$, but this just seems to lead to a wrong direction. Any hints on how to approach this better?

Answer (score 1):

You can proceed by double inclusion.

$U_a \times B \cap A \times U_b \subseteq  U_a \times U_b$

Take $(x,y) \in U_a \times B \cap A \times U_b$. This means that $(x,y)$ belongs to both $U_a \times B,A \times U_b$. And therefore that $x \in U_a$ and $y \in U_b$. Consequently $(x,y) \in U_a \times U_b$ as desired.

$ U_a \times U_b \subseteq  U_a \times B \cap A \times U_b$

$(x,y) \in U_a \times U_b$ means that $x \in U_a$ and $y \in U_b$. As $U_a \subseteq A$ and $U_b \subseteq B$, we also have $x \in A$ and $y \in B$. Therefore $(x,y)$ belongs to both $U_a \times B$ and $A \times U_b$. This implies that $(x,y)$ belongs to the intersection $U_a \times B \cap A \times U_b$.

We're done.